# How to verify if each element in a pandas columns increase strictly by +1 from row to row

Tags: python, pandas, increment

Let's say I have the following pandas.dataframe:

```
data

      series    time_idx    value
0        0          0      -0.000000
1        0          1       0.018844
2        0          2       0.028694
3        0          3       0.050784
4        0          4       0.067037
...      ...        ...     ...
3995     9          395     0.973978
3996     9          396     0.944002
3997     9          397     1.001089
3998     9          398     1.132001
3999     9          399     1.169244
4000 rows × 3 columns
```

I want to test if for each series (0..9) the time indexes are incremented by 1 from row to row and if not where the difference is?

I thought about sorting the dataframe by series and by time_index and then compare to the index mod 400, but it's not a nice solution. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is based on what I understand from your question.  See if this answers your question.  I have to use 'True' instead of Boolean True because the dataframe converts it to the numeric 1.0.

```
df['IncOne'] = (df.series==df.series.shift())
df['IncOne'] = (
    np.where(df.IncOne, 
        np.where( df.time_idx.eq(df.time_idx.shift()+1), 
                  'True' , df.time_idx-df.time_idx.shift() ),
    ''))
```

|  | series | time_idx | value | IncOne |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0.018844 | True |
| 2 | 0 | 2 | 0.028694 | True |
| 3 | 0 | 3 | 0.050784 | True |
| 4 | 0 | 4 | 0.067037 | True |
| 5 | 0 | 6 | 0 | 2.0 |
| 6 | 0 | 7 | 0.018844 | True |
| 7 | 0 | 8 | 0.028694 | True |
| 8 | 0 | 9 | 0.050784 | True |
| 9 | 0 | 12 | 0.067037 | 3.0 |
| 10 | 0 | 13 | 1 | True |
| 11 | 9 | 395 | 0.973978 |  |
| 12 | 9 | 396 | 0.944002 | True |
| 13 | 9 | 397 | 1.00109 | True |
| 14 | 9 | 398 | 1.132 | True |
| 15 | 9 | 399 | 1.16924 | True |

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the dataframe is `df` you can try this:

```
df["diff"] = df.groupby(by="series")["time_idx"].diff().fillna(1) != 1
```

It will create a new column `"diff"` with boolean values. A `True` value indicates that the difference between the `time_idx` value in the current row and the row preceding it is different than one. Only differences between rows corresponding to the same series can give a `True` value.